# Pointing canvas at my site always goes to /view

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-canvas

I'm just diving into the exciting world of facebook app creation, but have already run into a hopefully easy-to-fix snag. I'm following the step-by-step directions found at this URL: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/

I'm attempting to point the facebook app canvas to a URL (let's call it "http://mydomain.com/my/path/"). This URL, when I load it directly, displays a "hello word" message only, so there's no redirect or anything like that going on. Yet, no hatter if I use a secure or insecure connection, the canvas always seems to want to load up "http://mydomain.com/view" instead, which displays a 404 error message.

I'm just getting started, so I don't have anything configured past the "canvas URL" option (no authorization has been configured yet). I *suppose* I could just have "/view" display my facebook app on my server, but there are a couple of problems with that. 1) It conflicts with an already existing URL that my facebook app will eventually be hosted on and 2) According to the docs, this is undefined behavior, and I would like to know why that is.

Any help would be welcome, as I am stuck in mud right now. Thanks!

Comment: I figured out the problem. The server software I was using was performing a redirect "behind the scenes". I didn't see this until I had cranked up the logging a little. I have to fix this on my end. Sorry, and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The server software I was using was performing a redirect "behind the scenes". I didn't see this until I had cranked up the logging a little. I have fixed this on my end and now it all works as expected. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In your App settings you will notice a few URL fields. A Canvas Field, Page Canvas Field, etc... Please Paste the value of these fields (from your Facebook app settings page) for people to look at.

for instance, I have /show set up as the Canvas URL. and anytime anyone goes to my App, they see /show. Also, if you just changed the URL recently- you may notice some LAG as the setting change propagates to all the FB servers..

Comment: Right now I'm not ready to publicly broadcast my URL yet. That's why is used the pseudo-URL in my original post. To answer your question more generally, I only have two fields filled in, the Canvas URL and the Canvas secure URL. They both go to the same location, the difference being "http" and "https" as the protocols being used respectively. I left all the other fields blank as they appeared to have pertained to functionality that I have yet to implement (such as facebook user authentication, for example).

Comment: As for the time lag question you brought up, I created the application yesterday, left it overnight, and then tried it again this morning (almost 18 hours of time went by).

Comment: The path part of the URL I am using is "/app/usa/fb/". When I load my app under apps.facebook.com, I get this message:

Problem accessing /view. Reason:
    Not Found
Powered by Jetty://

Not surprisingly, I see this exact error message if I just load up http://mydomain.com/view directly. I can see that FB is indeed hitting our server in the logs, but it's going for /view, not the path I told to to load. That's what's leaving me scratching my head.